# System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject but running the query in Developer Console returns results

Tags: soql

I am new to Apex. Writing my first test class for a trigger.
I need to insert an opportunity for the test. The opportunity has a lookup to an object called Program__c. I am using SOQL to find the Program__c Id to be used in the opportunity creation. 
But I am getting the error 'List has no rows for assignment to SObject'.

```
 //get Program Id
    Program__c p = [SELECT Id from Program__c WHERE Name = 'Inspire Program Term 1' LIMIT 1];

    //insert Booking as Open
    Opportunity O = new Opportunity();
    O.RecordTypeId = rtO.Id;
    O.Name = 'Test';
    O.CloseDate = System.Today();
    O.AccountId = A.Id;
    O.Student_Attending__c = S.Id;
    O.StageName = 'Open';
    O.Program__c = p.Id;
```

But when I run the below SOQL in the Developer Console I get back the id.

`SELECT Id from Program__c WHERE Name = 'Inspire Program Term 1' LIMIT 1`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a Program object and name it that, this is rough but you should get the idea.  Also you will need to do the same thing with student if you haven't do so already.  You don't have access to data in test classes unless you use SeeAllData which is a no no, so you must build the objects you are attempting you use

```
Program__c p = new Program__c();
p.Name = 'Inspire Program Term 1';
insert p;
```